# Battery is charging, but stays at 0%. "Random" occurrence

Tags: laptop, battery, power, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo P52.
It is about 1 year old.
Since about one month ago, often times it shows 0% battery, charging (with the AC adapter plugged in), but the charge level stays at 0%.

I don't have a record of systematics on this, but so far, I could "fix" it a couple of times.
The first time, I don't recall what I tried and did to get it to charge again.
Then the problem started again, and I cannot identify any specific change either (other than unplugging it a few times).
Now, I have turned it off, removed the battery, blew on the contacts, and placed it back. I also unplugged and plugged again.
That is what I did, although it doesn't mean for sure that contacts were dirty or else.

The fact that it charges now (and after the first fix as well) suggests the battery is not dead.

**Did any one have a similar problem, and found a solution?**

In the meantime, I will try to collect more information, but that depends on the charging to start failing again.
One possibility is a faulty DC power jack.

**Related**

1. [Lenovo Laptop stuck at 0% plugged in, charging](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/lenovo-laptop-stuck-at-0-plugged-in-charging.204688/)
2. [Battery 'Plugged in, Charging' but stuck at 0%](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Battery-Plugged-in-Charging-but-stuck-at/m-p/1206398?page=1)
3. [Lenovo laptop is stuck at 0% battery with "plugged in, not charging"](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/462o2g/my_lenovo_laptop_is_stuck_at_0_battery_with_a/)
4. [Laptop Battery not charging "plugged in, not charging"](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/476827/Laptop+Battery+not+charging+%22plugged+in,+not+charging%22)
5. [Laptop says plugged in and charging but it still is on 0%](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Laptop-says-plugged-in-and-charging-but-it-still-is-on-0/td-p/4012791)
6. [0% available (plugged in, charging)](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/0-available-plugged-in-charging/td-p/4120934)
7. [0% available (plugged in, not charging)](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/0-available-plugged-in-not-charging/m-p/5130143#M921646)
8. [Battery stuck at "0% available plugged in, charging"](https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Battery-stuck-at-quot-0-available-plugged-in-charging-quot/td-p/7373087)

Comment: Get it serviced by Lenovo on warranty if possible.

Comment: _(Please use correct markdown for weblinks via the markdown formatting bar.)_ It sounds like the battery's: **(1)** dropped one or more cells _(replace battery)_; **(2)**  PCB has failed _(replace battery)_; **(3)** _(may not be applicable)_ Power brick's communication line has failed in the charging cable if Lenovo uses one in their power bricks, which is common with Dell laptops. General FYI: laptop batteries have a finite discharge/charge cycle (~300 - 500x) and generally only last for 1 - 2yrs without degradation; while it's less common for the battery's PCB to fail, it does happen

Comment: @JW0914 - I do not know what markdown you consider incorrect.
Thanks for the comment, which could well be an answer. Do you know of a way to diagnose (without further instruments) if any of your 3 options applies?

Comment: Weblink markdown is linked to a word, not listed in physical URL form, which is inefficient [waste of space] and provides no context. It's far more likely you have a bad battery - does the DC jack have three points of contact via a center pin _(e.g. points of contact on the DC jack would be the outer metal jacket, the inner metal jacket, and a center pin, with the center pin being the communication line - due to the communication line being a tiny gauge wire, it's common for the wire to break from normal usage of unplugging/plugging in the DC jack)_?

Comment: @JW0914 - The way you list web links is certainly a good option, and I use it often times.
OTOH, I doubt it can be named the "correct" form. 
Moreover, I sometimes intentionally use URLs (as I did here). It is also instructive to see directly the URL (I know hovering the mouse would show it if not listed directly).
I guess the fact that Markdown allows for it is a sign that one may want that...

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio The correct markdown for weblinks is to have them linked to a word, not be in URL form, which is why the _Link_ button exists on the markdown formatting toolbar. I edited the links to be the title of the page they direct to since it was the safest assumption that kept the content true to your intent, however a URL could be linked to just one word.

Answer (score 2):

> **Did any one have a similar problem,**

Yes. I had this problem on my Lenovo X230.

I did the same as you - turn off, remove the battery, replace it and start up.  I think that resets the battery information within the Lenovo Vantage Battery health section.

If your action above works in the longer term, you can consider it as a one-time random occurrence.

You might wish to reset your battery. Open Lenovo Vantage, Power, and in that screen is the Battery Reset function. Do the reset (takes a few hours so consider starting it just before retiring for the evening).

I have performed the Battery Reset on both my Lenovo laptops. Once you do the Reset, you can set the Battery Threshold to 80% Max, 75% Min. This is good for the battery if you leave the computer plugged in all the time.

If the issue continues to happen, then contact Lenovo Support and see about getting it serviced.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this feature.